# Getting the number of comments from a specific post in django

Tags: python, django, web, blogs

I have a little problem with a query. I work on a blog website with django. For posts I have the first page where i display all the posts as a list, with their details (title, date posted etc.) and I want to display the number of comments for each post along with title, date posted and tags. I'm not sure how to make that, I need to implement something on the model classes or in view function that renders the page ?
Here are the model classes.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Comment ' + str(self.id)
```

and the view function

```
def blog(request):

    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Blog',
        'banner_page_title': 'Blog',
        'page_location': 'Home / Blog'
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1:

You can use this in your template.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.comment_set.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Method 2:

You can implement a model method like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def comment_count(self):
        return self.comment_set.count()
```

And you can call the model method in your template like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.comment_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reverse lookup in the template and `count` to get the number of related objects:

```
{{ post.comment_set.count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**template.html**

```
...
{% for post in posts %}
  <div> Title: {{post.title}} </div>
  <div> Date Posted: {{post.date_posted}} </div>
  <div> Number of Comments: {{post.comment_set.count}} </div>
{% endfor %}
```